# Returning the deleted item after using array_pop

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
$my_array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
```

How can I return the deleted item after using **shuffle($my_array)** and **array_pop($my_array)**?

I want something like:
The deleted number is: **3**.

This is my code:

```
$my_array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
shuffle($my_array)
array_pop($my_array)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP documentation, [array_pop()](https://php.net/array_pop) will return the value that was deleted:

```
Return Values

Returns the value of the last element of array. If array is empty (or is not an array), NULL will be returned.
```

**So, you can simply do:**

```
$my_array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
shuffle($my_array);
echo 'The deleted number is: <b>'.array_pop($my_array).'</b>';
```